# What are the possible values of display property in ComputedStyle mode

Tags: css, qt, dom, webkit, qtwebkit

I am using QtWebkit. I am calling this method:

```
documentElement.styleProperty('display', QWebElement.ComputedStyle)
```

I want to know out of the possible values of display which are

```
'block'
'compact'
'inherit'
'inline'
'inline-block'
'inline-table'
'list-item'
'marker'
'none'
'run-in'
'table'
'table-caption'
'table-cell'
'table-column'
'table-column-group'
'table-footer-group'
'table-header-group'
'table-row'
'table-row-group'
```

what values are possible in ComputedStyle? Till now I have seen none, block, inline and list-item on some of the webpages.

Comment: why do you think the list should be different? (and what would you use that information for?)

Comment: for values like 'inherit', 'run-in' I guess it should be _computed_ to other values.

Comment: well, yes, that sounds reasonable. still doesn't explain what you could do if you knew the exact subset it could return. that might change from version to version, it will change with CSS versions, etc.

Comment: @Mat yeah thanks for reminding me of CSS versions :) and now this puts more work in my task.

Answer (score 0):

from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop

inline | block | list-item | inline-block | table | inline-table | table-row-group | table-header-group | table-footer-group | table-row | table-column-group | table-column | table-cell | table-caption | none | inherit

Comment: that's not what is being asked.